# Error connecting EOne SmartConnect to Magento SOAP interface

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento V 1.9.2.4

When I try to connect the SmartConnect soap client to my Magento server i am getting the error:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.myurl.com:443/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' 
: failed to load external entity "https://www.myurl.com:443/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1"
```

A posting I found seemed to indicate that the server could not access itself. It said to make sure that your have an entry in \etc\host that points to itself. I have done so. It also mentioned using curl to test the connection. Using curl returned the following:

```
~$ curl https://www.myurl.com:443/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

When I used curl with the -k option, I get the wsdl information returned correctly.

At this point I am not sure what to do. My ssl has been working fine with my Storefront for months.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.